# Dummit and Foote's proof of row rank of any matrix equals column rank.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, vector-spaces

**The Problem**: In the textbook, the proof goes:

> Let $\varphi: V\to W$ be a linear transformation whose matrix with respect to some fixed bases of $V$ and $W$ is $A$... Now $f\in ker \varphi^*\iff... \varphi(V)\subseteq ker f\iff f\in Ann(\varphi(V))$, where $Ann(S)$ is the annihilator of $S$ described in Exercise $3$ below.

But in Exercise $3$, $S$ is a subset of $V^*$ for a finite dimensional space $V$, which obviously is a set of linear transformations, hence is not even the same object as $\varphi(V)$ (which is a set of vectors in $W$).

**My Question**: What exactly am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with reflexivity?

Comment: @blargoner Reflexivity as in equivalence relations? Affirmative.

Comment: No as in $W$ being naturally isomorphic to $W^{**}$.

Comment: @blargoner I am aware of that too.

Comment: That means you can identify $W$ with $(W^*)^*$, so $\varphi(V)\subseteq(W^*)^*$, and you can take $V=W^*$ in Exercise 3.

Comment: @blargoner I see-that makes more sense. Thank you so much!